# How to aggregate irregularly sampled data for Time Series Analysis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, data-science

I am trying to forecast daily profit using time series analysis, but daily profit is not only recorded unevenly, but some of the data is missing.

Raw Data:

| Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2020/1/19 | 10$ |
| 2020/1/20 | 7$ |
| 2020/1/25 | 14$ |
| 2020/1/29 | 18$ |
| 2020/2/1 | 12$ |
| 2020/2/2 | 17$ |
| 2020/2/9 | 28$ |

The above table is an example of what kind of data I have. Profit is not recorded daily, so date between 2020/1/20 and 2020/1/24 does not exist. Not only that, say the profit recorded during the period between 2020/2/3 and 2020/3/8 went missing in the database. I would like to recover this missing data and use time series analysis to predict the profit after 2020/2/9 ~.

My approach was to first aggregate the profit every 6 days since I have to recover the profit between 2020/2/3 and 2020/3/8. So my cleaned data will look something like this

| Date | Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2020/1/16 ~ 2020/1/21 | 17$ |
| 2020/1/22 ~ 2020/1/27 | 14$ |
| 2020/1/28 ~ 2020/2/2 | 47$ |
| 2020/2/3 ~ 2020/2/8 | ? (to predict) |

After applying this to a time series model, I would like to further predict the profit after 2020/2/9 ~.
This is my general idea, but as a beginner at Python, using pandas library, I have trouble executing my ideas. Could you please help me how to aggregate the profit every 6 days and have the data look like the above table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using a combination of [`.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html), [`pd.date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html), and [`.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html)

Say your `DataFrame` is `df`, with proper datetime indexing:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2020/1/19',10],
                   ['2020/1/20',7],
                   ['2020/1/25',14],
                   ['2020/1/29',18],
                   ['2020/2/1',12],
                   ['2020/2/2',17],
                   ['2020/2/9',28]],columns=['Date','Revenue'])

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.set_index('Date',inplace=True)
```

The first step is to 'fill in' the missing days with dummy, zero revenue. We can use `pd.date_range` to get an index with evenly spaced dates from 2020/1/16 to 2020/2/8, and then `.reindex` to bring this into the main `df` `DataFrame`:

```
evenly_spaced_idx = pd.date_range(start='2020/1/16',end='2020/2/8',freq='1d')
df = df.reindex(evenly_spaced_idx, fill_value=0)
```

Now we can take a rolling sum for each 6 day period. We're not interested in every day's six day revenue total, only every 6th days, though:

```
summary_df = df.rolling('6d').sum().iloc[5::6, :]
```

The last thing with `summary_df` is just to format it the way you'd like so that it clearly states the date range which each row refers to.

```
summary_df['Start Date'] = summary_df.index-pd.Timedelta('6d')
summary_df['End Date'] = summary_df.index
summary_df.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is using pandas `resample` function.

Provided you have an index of type `Datetime` resampling to aggregate profits at every 6 days would be as simple as `your_dataframe.resample('6D').sum()`

You can do all sorts of resampling (end of month, end of quarter, begining of week, every hour, minute, second, ...). Check the full documentation if you're interested: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html?highlight=resample#pandas.DataFrame.resample

Answer (score 0):

You can use `resample` for this.

Make sure to have the "Date" column as datetime type.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([["2020/1/19"  ,10],
    ... ["2020/1/20"  ,7],
    ... ["2020/1/25"  ,14],
    ... ["2020/1/29"  ,18],
    ... ["2020/2/1"  ,12],
    ... ["2020/2/2"  ,17],
    ... ["2020/2/9"  ,28]], columns=['Date', 'Revenue'])
>>> df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

**For pandas < 1.1.0**

```
>>> df.set_index('Date').resample('6D', base=3).sum()
            Revenue
Date
2020-01-16       17
2020-01-22       14
2020-01-28       47
2020-02-03        0
2020-02-09       28
```

**For pandas >= 1.1.0**

```
>>> df.set_index('Date').resample('6D', origin='2020-01-16').sum()
            Revenue
Date
2020-01-16       17
2020-01-22       14
2020-01-28       47
2020-02-03        0
2020-02-09       28
```